# HAL Browser redirect behind reverse proxy does not work

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-data, hal

I have a Spring Data REST application with a HAL Browser attached to it.
The application runs on `localhost:8080/app/`, and so the HAL browser runs at `localhost:8080/app/browser/index.html#/app/`.

The hal browser has one java file that redirects calls to `/app` to `/app/browser/dinex.html#/app`. This file: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-hal-browser/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/halbrowser/HalBrowser.java

Now, this application runs behind a reverse proxy (apache httpd). There I have the following rules:

```
ProxyPass         /hal/ http://localhost:8080/app/
ProxyPassReverse  /hal/ http://server1/app/
```

So requests to `http://server1/hal/browser/index.html#/hal/` show a working HAL browser.

However, requests to `http://server1/hal/` will get a 302 (from application) with a `Location` header with in it `http://server1/hal/browser/index.html#/app/`.  This won't work because the part behind the #.

I think I understand that `ProxyPassReverse` is not meant to also rewrite things behind the `#` hashtag.

So, what is my problem here? Is the HAL browser incorrectly adding a hashtag to the `Location` tag? Or is this normal behaviour and can Apache solve this?